# Can't read a UTF8 encoded file using fopen(file, "r,ccs=UTF-8")

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, fopen

I'm using ccs=encoding (as described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) to set the encoding to UTF-8 when opening a file with fopen.

When writing to a file it works fine

```
wchar_t* unicode_text = L"こんにちは";
FILE* f = fopen("C:\\test.txt", "w,ccs=UTF-8");
fwprintf(f, L"%s\n", unicode_text);
fclose(f);
```

When I open the file in a text editor the unicode shows as it should.
But when trying to read from the created file the UTF-8 encoding is not detected:

```
wchar_t buffer[1000];
FILE* f = fopen("C:\\test.txt", "r,ccs=UTF-8");
fgetws(buffer, 1000, f);
fclose(f);

MessageBoxW(0, buffer, 0, 0);
```

This shows "ï»¿ããã«ã¡ã¯" in the message box.

Why does this happen? Is ccs=UTF-8 only valid when opening files for writing?

Comment: `ï»¿ããã«ã¡ã¯` would definitely not be ASCII. In fact, it's entirely *non*-ASCII.

Comment: Fair enough, I've deleted the part about the ASCII.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this ugly nonstandard hack rather than just either requiring a UTF-8 locale to begin with or using `iconv` (the clean/portable way)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation implies that UTF-8 encoding is only available for writing (emphasis mine):

> In Visual C++ 2005, fopen supports Unicode file streams. A flag specifying the desired encoding may be passed to fopen when **opening a new file** or **overwriting an existing file**, like this:

Note that "reading an existing file" is conspicuously absent.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll be using fgets+mbstowcs then.

Comment: Just below it is said in MSDN: "If the file is already in existence and is opened for reading or appending, the Byte Order Mark (BOM) is used to determine the correct encoding. ... The flag is only used when no BOM is present or if the file is a new file."

Comment: @alexander, as I said it "implies" without being definitive. I took that statement to describe what happens when a file is opened for overwriting.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
#include <locale.h>

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Japanese");
```

Comment: I think you may be right that the problem is missing call to `setlocale`, but `"Japanese"` is not the right argument to it.

Comment: What about,
In the console application in my environment, `setlocale (LC_ALL," Japanese ");` was able to output to the console without garbage by  `wprintf (L"% s ", buffer);`. So, `fgetws (buffer, 1000, f);` I think that as the behavior of is able to read correctly.
Is `MessageBoxW`, `setlocale (LC_ALL," Japanese ")` in the environment in the vs2010 of japanese version might be another problem that can be displayed properly because even if you do not set even if you set`.

Comment: The problem might be the default font.

Answer (score 0):

see [fgets,fgetws](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c37dh6kf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> fgetws reads the wide-character argument str as a multibyte-character
>   string or a wide-character string according to whether stream is
>   opened in text mode or binary mode,

If you try the "rb".

Answer (score 0):

It might be as easy as stripping the BOM off of the text. It looks like the first three chars that are showing up in your text box ("ï»¿") is the BOM for UTF-8 files:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding